# Scrapy parse redirection first

Tags: python, parsing, redirect, scrapy

I have some code here that is meant to detect a redirection while scraping and then return a request for the page that it was being redirected to so that I can parse the redirected page.  However I let the scraper run for a long while and nothing ever came up in regards to parsing the redirected page.  Keep in mind the fact that my start_urls list is dynamically generated and can be terribly long at times.  What I am trying to accomplish is for the scraper to

1. Detect redirection
2. Stop scraping of start_urls or whatever is in the queue
3. Parse redirection
4. Scrape original page redirected from, and continue scraping of start_urls

Scraping the original page shouldnt be too complicated and I already have that section of the code handled in the else statement.  My main issue is the first 3 tasks.  I want to move the redirection parsing to the top of the scrapers priority list.  How can I do this?

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.logger.info("got response %d for %r" % (response.status, response.url))

    # handle redirection
    # this is copied/adapted from RedirectMiddleware
    if response.status == 302:

        self.logger.info("Response is 302")

        location = to_native_str(response.headers['location'].decode('latin1'))

        self.logger.info("Location: %s" % location)

        # get the original request
        request = response.request
        # and the URL we got redirected to
        redirected_url = urljoin(request.url, location)

        self.logger.info("Redirected_url: %s" % redirected_url)

        self.logger.info("Yielding redirect instead")
        return scrapy.Request(redirected_url, callback=self.parse, meta={'dont_redirect':True})
    else:
        #parse the redirected page
```

Comment: It depends on how the redirection is initiated. If it's an HTTP 3xx redirection or meta-refresh redirection, the built-in redirect middleware shall have already handle d it for you (you're able to disable/bypass the builtin redirect functionality if you want to handle it yourself). But a JS initiated redirection is not something Scrapy can handle. Before trying to work it out in the scraper, you'll need to first make sure what exactly is the case on the actual website.

Comment: It's redirected to a google captcha page that is built in to the site.  I don't know if it's JS initiated or not I haven't been able to see a specific pattern of events but it does seem to be cookie related, as once the captcha is solved, it doesn't appear again. As far as I know the redirect middle wares does get enabled from this in my start requests function: `yield scrapy.Request(x, callback=self.parse, meta={'dont_redirect':False})` as far as I know... But then obviously disabled in the code above. I think I want to handle it manually but, then again I am not educated on how to handle it.